# Pass value from input field to localstorage and access it in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass the values of my input fields to my js function which is in another div. I think I'm not too far away from the correct solution but it does not work and returns just an empty value.

```
<div id="Page1" class="page" style="">
Firstname: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"></br>
Date of Birth: <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob"></br>
<button onclick="locstor()" type="button">Save>
<script>
function locstor(){
  localStorage.setItem("firstname", $("#firstname").val());
localStorage.setItem("dob", $("#dob").val());
    }
</script>     
</div>
```

...
In another div:

```
var probe1 = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
var probe2 = localStorage.getItem("dob");
var teststim =  [probe1, "ERIC", "CHRIS", "PAUL", "ALEX", "JACK",
                 probe2, "4 APRIL", "27 JUNE", "9 DECEMBER", "19 MARCH", "20 OCTOBER"];
```

If I call an alert with probe1 or probe2 as test, it's empty.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Open your console (F12) and check for errors.

Comment: I did, there are no errors.

Comment: Your code works fine, you must be executing the code in your other div before you set localStorage. If you do `console.log(localStorage.getItem("firstname"))` right after your setItem, it displays right